# Node.js install cloudant module

Tags: node.js, cordova, module, cloudant

Hi I am making a Cordova app for iOS and Android. I am trying to use the cloudant module `https://github.com/cloudant/nodejs-cloudant` to access my cloudant couchDB, but for the life of me, I cannot figure out the issue I am having while installing it. Using linux, I executed `npm install --save cloudant` at the root of my Cordova project folder. When using `var Cloudant = cordova.require('cloudant');` in my code, I get the error `Uncaught module cloudant not found` from within my cordova.js file as it tries to load the module. Also when I run `$ node -e 'require("cloudant"); console.log("Cloudant works");'` in my shell, I receive a terminal output stating "Cloudant works". I cannot seem to figure out what the issue is, and have tried many different things. Any help is extremely appreciated, as I am at my witts end at this point. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As @Parth says, 'nodejs-cloudant' is a Node.js/npm module. To access Cloudant from within your Cordova application you will need client side code to interact with Cloudant's HTTP API.

You could use jQuery's Ajax functions to make HTTP requests to Cloudant or you can use [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/) as a client-side library e.g:

```
   <script src="pouchdb-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
   <script>
      var db = new PouchDB("https://myusername:mypassword@myaccount.cloudant.com/mydb";
   </script>
```

Both solutions require you to [enable CORS on your Cloudant account](https://docs.cloudant.com/api.html#cors).

Answer (score 0):

'nodejs-cloudant' is an npm module and not a cordova module. you just need to write 
`var Cloudant = require('cloudant');` That should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
var Cloudant = require('cloudant');
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing cloudant directly, try using cradle or nano for accessing cloudant 
   'DB.const nano = require('nano')('//cloudant api link//');'
This works
https://www.npmjs.com/package/nano#dbinsertdoc-params-callback
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cradle